Issue when debugging remotely with vscode to a rpi
I have a ssh connection to the RPi and it is working and alle the files transport correctly but I won't debug, when I run the dll on the rpi it works fin, can you guys help
I have this task.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "RaspberryPublish",
            "command": "sh",
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "args": [
                "-c",
                "\"dotnet publish -r linux-arm -o bin/linux-arm/publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}.csproj\"",
                ";",
                "sh",
                "-c",
                "\"rsync -rvuz ${workspaceFolder}/bin/linux-arm/publish/ pi@raspberrypi.local:~/Programs/${workspaceFolderBasename}\""
            ]
        }
    ]
}

and this launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Raspberry Pi Publish, Launch, and Attach Debugger",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "RaspberryPublish",
            "program": "~/Programs/${workspaceFolderBasename}/${workspaceFolderBasename}",
            "cwd": "~/Programs/${workspaceFolderBasename}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "args": [
                "https://your-dmx-function.azurewebsites.net/api"
            ],
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "pipeProgram": "/usr/bin/ssh",
                "pipeArgs": [
                    "pi@raspberrypi.local"
                ],
                "debuggerPath": "~/vsdbg/vsdbg"
            },
            "justMyCode": false,
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": true,
                "trace": true,
                "programOutput": true
            },
        }
    ]
}

I have try to debug it and establish a ssh connection to the pi and run it without debugging
